# Rcpp Compilation error with match()

Tags: c++, r, match, rcpp

I would like to use the sugar match function for the ComplexVector type and I am getting the error

```
g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"*path*"
-I"*path*"  -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/include"     
-O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c setdiffComplexVectorsC.cpp 
-o setdiffComplexVectorsC.o
g++ -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o sourceCpp_38.dll tmp.def 
setdiffComplexVectorsC.o -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/lib/x64
-Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/lib 
-LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64 
-lR setdiffComplexVectorsC.o:setdiffComplexVectorsC.cpp:(.text+0x5e0):
 undefined reference to `Rcpp::sugar::IndexHash<15>::get_addr(Rcomplex) const'
setdiffComplexVectorsC.o:setdiffComplexVectorsC.cpp:(.text+0x788): undefined 
reference to `Rcpp::sugar::IndexHash<15>::get_addr(Rcomplex) const'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp("setdiffComplexVectorsC.cpp") : 

**Error occurred building shared library.**
```

With the following code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;
using namespace sugar;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
ComplexVector setdiffComplexVectorsC(ComplexVector        
ComplexVector2Curt,ComplexVector ComplexVector2compare){
// setdiffComplexVectors shortens ComplexVector2Curt by those rows that 
//are   in both matrices.
// INPUT
// ComplexVector2Curt(n)            complexvector, which will be shortened by ComplexVector2compare
// ComplexVector2compare(m)         complexvector whose elements will be compared to those of ComplexVector2Curt
//
// OUTPUT
// CurtedComplexVector[n-x]           complexvector, Shortened ComplexVector2Curt 
                                     //by x same elements of ComplexVector2compare


IntegerVector Y = match(ComplexVector2Curt,ComplexVector2compare);

  //FoundPositions <- ComplexVector2Curt[Y];
 int n=sum(abs(Y-1)); //length of open positions (FALSE)
 if(n<1){
   ComplexVector Nix;
   return(Nix);
 }
 //ComplexVector OpenPositions  = ComplexVector2Curt[!Y];
 ComplexVector OpenPositions(n);
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
   if(Y(i)==0){
     OpenPositions(i)= ComplexVector2Curt(i);
   }
 }
return(OpenPositions);

}
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?
Maybe someone has an idea how to compare ComplexVectors another way: the goal is finding non-matching elements of "ComplexVector2Curt".

Comment: Are you looking for the equivalent of `x[!(x %in% y)]`? The [R API](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/include/Rinternals.h), also, provides a `match` function you could check.

Comment: yes and I am using currently the R match function:  My Code has a for loop, which I would like to port to C++, and for this I have to use this function in C++, where I am getting the above error.

Comment: Maybe it does not accept "complex" (CPLXSXP) as input?

Answer (score 3):

`Rcpp::match` relies on the backend `IndexHash` template class, and in particular, implicitly requires an overload of `IndexHash<>::get_addr`, which [does not exist](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/9642541239f0985d0f211d106f2cdc3169806d23/inst/include/Rcpp/hash/IndexHash.h##L203-L234) for `Rcomplex` / `CPLXSXP` types.

---

One workaround is to implement this sort of functionality with a `std::map`. Note that this will *not* be as efficient as a proper hash table solution, as Rcpp implements, but it is much quicker to prototype. First, some boilerplate code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

struct CxLess {
    bool operator()(Rcomplex lhs, Rcomplex rhs) const {
        if (lhs.r < rhs.r) return true;
        if (lhs.i < rhs.i) return true;
        return false;
    }
};

class CxMatch {
private:
    typedef std::map<Rcomplex, int, CxLess> hash_t;
    typedef hash_t::const_iterator const_iterator;
    typedef hash_t::iterator iterator;

    hash_t hash;

    void add_if(Rcomplex key, R_xlen_t value) {
        const_iterator it = hash.find(key);
        if (it == hash.end()) {
            hash[key] = value;
        }
    }

public:
    CxMatch(const Rcpp::ComplexVector& v) {
        R_xlen_t i = 0, sz = v.size();
        for ( ; i < sz; i++) {
            add_if(v[i], i);
        }
    }

    int get_index(Rcomplex key) const {
        const_iterator it = hash.find(key);
        if (it != hash.end()) return it->second;
        return NA_INTEGER;
    }

    Rcpp::IntegerVector apply(Rcpp::ComplexVector x) const {
        R_xlen_t i = 0, sz = x.size();
        Rcpp::IntegerVector res(sz);

        for ( ; i < sz; i++) {
            res[i] = get_index(x[i]);
        }

        return res;
    }
};
```

---

The `CxLess` functor is necessary because, by default, `std::map` will attempt to use `std::less<key_type>` as a comparator, which would cause a compiler error with Rcomplex. Using the above,

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::ComplexVector cx_setdiff(Rcpp::ComplexVector lhs, Rcpp::ComplexVector rhs) {
    Rcpp::IntegerVector match_pos = CxMatch(rhs).apply(lhs);
    Rcpp::LogicalVector idx = Rcpp::is_na(match_pos);
    return lhs[idx];
}
```

---

Running a couple of basic tests, this seems to produce the desired behavior:

```
setdiff(c(1, 3, 5, 7, 11) + 2i, 1:10 + 2i)
#[1] 11+2i

cx_setdiff(c(1, 3, 5, 7, 11) + 2i, 1:10 + 2i)
#[1] 11+2i

setdiff(c(1, 3, 5, 7) + 2i, 1:10 + 2i)
#complex(0)

cx_setdiff(c(1, 3, 5, 7) + 2i, 1:10 + 2i)
#complex(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]

ComplexVector setdiffComplexVectorsC(ComplexVector ComplexVector2Curt,  ComplexVector ComplexVector2compare){

LogicalVector x(ComplexVector2Curt.size());

 int i,j;

 for(i=0; i < ComplexVector2Curt.size();i++){

   for(j=0; j < ComplexVector2compare.size();j++){

     if((ComplexVector2Curt[i].i == ComplexVector2compare[j].i) &&

        (ComplexVector2Curt[i].r == ComplexVector2compare[j].r))

       x[i] = true;

   }

 }

 return(ComplexVector2Curt[!x]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of commenting both approaches separately, I post an answer (for future readers):
I managed to find an real world example, where both approaches fail.
I am sorry that I was not able to find an shorter example:
x and y are unique. Therefore, the result of setdiff() should be unique. Approach one (cx_setdiff) does not change x. Approach 2 (setdiffComplexVectorsC) is not unique. Both results are different in comparison to R's setdiff().

```
> length(unique(setdiff(x,y)))
[1] 46
> length((setdiff(x,y)))
[1] 46

> length(unique(setdiffComplexVectorsC(x,y)))
[1] 41
length(setdiffComplexVectorsC(x,y))
[1] 46
> length(unique(cx_setdiff(x,y)))
[1] 52
all(cx_setdiff(x,y)==x)
[1] TRUE

x=c(16+35i, 16+36i, 16+47i, 16+48i, 17+33i, 17+51i, 18+30i, 18+53i, 
19+29i, 19+55i, 20+27i, 20+56i, 22+25i, 22+58i, 24+23i, 24+60i, 
25+23i, 25+61i, 32+19i, 32+64i, 33+19i, 33+65i, 36+18i, 36+65i, 
38+18i, 38+65i, 40+18i, 40+65i, 42+18i, 42+65i, 45+19i, 45+65i, 
46+19i, 46+64i, 3+23i, 3+61i, 4+23i, 4+60i, 6+25i, 6+58i, 8+27i, 
8+56i, 9+29i, 9+55i, 10+30i, 10+53i, 11+33i, 11+51i, 12+35i, 
12+36i, 12+47i, 12+48i)
length(unique(x))
[1] 52
> length(x)
[1] 52

y=c(25+76i, 15+39i, 48+31i, 14+13i, 8+70i, 22+34i, 39+31i, 38+66i, 
30+8i, 50+72i, 46+55i, 21+47i, 45+44i, 38+77i, 1+77i, 22+13i, 
2+3i, 38+24i, 49+1i, 42+19i, 45+58i, 14+64i, 40+77i, 50+4i, 10+20i, 
34+76i, 4+79i, 17+26i, 30+41i, 10+30i, 6+20i, 7+65i, 19+13i, 
13+14i, 6+30i, 25+4i, 32+75i, 26+33i, 3+16i, 41+57i, 17+52i, 
14+58i, 4+23i, 36+79i, 24+41i, 37+64i, 3+23i, 37+69i, 43+32i, 
25+63i, 1+34i, 44+68i, 0+0i, 24+44i, 20+70i, 2+17i, 32+78i, 44+8i, 
9+21i, 38+54i, 2+60i, 27+80i, 16+17i, 13+6i, 23+15i, 33+73i, 
24+1i, 18+57i, 9+49i, 4+32i, 25+5i, 35+21i, 36+33i, 14+29i, 11+74i, 
43+48i, 36+44i, 11+61i, 18+3i, 26+2i, 31+71i, 46+73i, 28+1i, 
28+57i, 23+52i, 25+79i, 10+56i, 50+43i, 25+46i, 32+76i, 6+77i, 
48+12i, 28+62i, 16+12i, 33+74i, 34+72i, 45+27i, 47+26i, 48+4i, 
45+68i, 14+59i, 47+2i, 29+69i, 2+46i, 9+34i, 7+36i, 28+28i, 42+44i, 
33+28i, 9+8i, 18+21i, 43+69i, 46+7i, 2+80i, 33+7i, 15+38i, 48+78i, 
47+57i, 50+53i, 14+42i, 44+17i, 26+25i, 50+5i, 33+18i, 6+28i, 
28+2i, 26+55i, 3+56i, 32+28i, 5+69i, 47+31i, 30+28i, 40+43i, 
41+67i, 2+2i, 36+18i, 26+27i, 10+65i, 37+27i, 32+42i, 37+72i, 
44+9i, 22+15i, 42+75i, 42+27i, 42+29i, 35+38i, 32+12i, 20+62i, 
28+52i, 13+58i, 40+22i, 6+3i, 9+75i, 6+55i, 18+73i, 35+32i, 35+59i, 
32+39i, 28+63i, 18+51i, 22+36i, 29+54i, 23+56i, 19+1i, 5+38i, 
25+64i, 50+46i, 48+59i, 8+58i, 10+40i, 12+40i, 19+72i, 12+8i, 
17+50i, 15+30i, 17+6i, 32+73i, 47+11i, 21+5i, 11+63i, 35+42i, 
31+13i, 33+51i, 29+68i, 9+9i, 13+59i, 44+40i, 20+73i, 21+41i, 
36+37i, 32+64i, 42+46i, 17+25i, 46+25i, 24+30i, 7+10i, 24+27i, 
11+73i, 27+27i, 15+12i, 2+9i, 16+36i, 6+61i, 48+20i, 27+15i, 
14+49i, 40+44i, 35+44i, 30+66i, 46+71i, 38+58i)

length(unique(y))
[1] 212
length(y)
[1] 212
```

Thank you for trying. Now I know for sure, that I need a self-made implementation for this problem. If I find a fix for one of the above approaches, I will post it here. Maybe even someone else sees the problem immediately.